# Can't download Minecraft Bedrock on multiple devices

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I downloaded Minecraft Bedrock edition on my Windows 10 computer, and I want to download it on Windows 10 laptop, but it doesn't show in Microsoft store when I go to my library.

Comment: Are you signed in on the same account you first bought it on?

Comment: if you bought mc from a microsoft account of some email address abcxyz@emailprovider.com, then make sure you signed in from thee same microsoft account, and intead of looking for the game in your library, search for the version you bought(starter/pro), and it should say you own this product and the install button should be there, if it doesn't work, try contacting mc through their support numbers in the website, or contact microsoft

Answer (score 1):

Download the Free Trial and link your Xbox account. That will let the game know you have progress and it will let you play the full version.